# Find the equation of the hyperbola that satisfies this condition

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Focus is at $F\equiv(−3−3√13, 1)$, asymptotes intersect at the point with coordinates $(−3, 1)$ and one asymptote passes through $(1, 7)$

I've solved some problems that involve equations of hyperbolas but this one got me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

- $(-3,1)$ is center.
- the two asymtotes are lines passing through $(-3,1)$. One passes through $(1,7)$ , other through focus , write their equation, find angle between them ($\theta$), then eccentricity is $\sec\theta/2$.
- length of semi-major axis is distance between center and focus.
- Now you have everything you need.